# MYSQL DATE function running insanely slow in LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, left-join

When adding the line:

```
LEFT JOIN core_records_sales as sales ON DATE(appointments.date) = DATE(sales.date_sold)
```

To my query, it boosts the time for the script to run from about 8 seconds, to 2-3 minutes.

Would there be some data causing this problem or am I not implementing the function correctly?

I need to use DATE() because I need them to be the same day but the date fields are DATETIME

Comment: How many rows in each table and which columns are indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly an issue with the appointments.date field being indexed.  Adding the use of the DATE() function makes it so that index cannot be used, forcing a table scan.

I've had to deal with this before, and the best way I've found to solve the issue is to have a separate column with just the date part (no time) in it or to store the date and time in two separate columns.

I'd love to hear if others have a better way of dealing with that though.

Comment: Unfortunately might have to go this route. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on the date column? Joining without an index requires a full table scan, so that's likely the cause of the performance issue.

Run your query through an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) to see what the query optimizer comes up with for the query plan.

Comment: Seeing as how OP's underlying columns are DATETIME, index won't really help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're forcing a full table scan on both tables whereas previously you were using an index as part of the query.  You need to examine the plan (and provide us with a little more detail too) so run it through EXPLAIN to see what's happening.