# How to optimize this query using better date comparsion in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, date-comparison

I have problem with this query, complexity of this query is not good, i use this query from long time and now this database have many rows to get selecting by this method. All index'es is added propertly. I searching some other method to optimize this query by date comparsion because this is bottleneck in this solution.

```
SELECT (...) FROM table 
WHERE (YEAR(row_add_date) * 10000 + 
       MONTH(row_add_date) * 100 + 
       DAYOFMONTH(row_add_date)) >= (var_0 * 10000 + var_1 * 100 + var_2) and
      (YEAR(row_add_date) * 10000 + 
       MONTH(row_add_date) * 100 + 
       DAYOFMONTH(row_add_date)) <= (var_3 * 10000 + var_4 * 100 + var_5)
```

Can anyone help me?
Greetings

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765667/mysql-date-function-running-insanely-slow-in-left-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using built-in mysql date comparisons.

```
row_add_date <= '20101027' and row_add_date >= '20101027'
```

But note that this is a strange test in the first place: aren't just testing that the date is equal to October 27th, like this:

```
row_add_date = '20101027'
```

Comment: '0'=0 this is '0'=var_1 in practice, i miss this.

Comment: Thanks this solved problem and query runs 372 times faster. I trying this but with '-' bettwen values but then this dont work.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you breaking apart the date like that? Per-row functions do *not* scale well. It seems to me that the entire date section at the end can be replaced by:

```
where row_add_date = '2010-10-27'
```

Even if you want a range, you're still better of using the dates as they are.

---

Based on your edits to state that you're using variables, you should do the calculation on the right-hand side of the conditions. That's because this will be done *once* before the query start. With what you have, the calculation on the left side will be done once per row, a definite performance killer.

Comment: Close, it could be replaced with `row_add_date >= '2010-10-27' and row_add_date < '2010-10-28'`

Comment: Wow, you're right :) completely missed that. it looked so terrible I didn't to try and understand the calculation

Comment: I updated question, this values are variable and are not equal in query, sorry for miss this.

Comment: @Andomar, how is that different than `= '2010-10-27`? Unless you're suggesting the columns at timestamps rather than dates. I assumed otherwise.

Comment: I assumed it was a `datetime` column, mainly because SQL Server 2005 doesn't have a `date` type I guess.  But if it's a `date` column you are right

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that row_add_date is of type `datetime`. If so, you need turn 20101027 into a `datetime`, and compare the column to that.

In other words:

```
row_add_date >= firstDateTime and row_add_date <= secondDateTime
```